# Control android tv-box with my tv's remote?

Tags: remote-control

I have an AmLogic M8 android tv-box which has an ir-reciever on it. The box came with an ir-remote that works fine. But I would like to use only my universal remote that comes with direct tv to control everything (I'm already using it to control my tv). I'm wondering if the is an app that can learn arbitrary ir codes and assign them to remote control functions.

I know how to control the box with my phone through ir as well as VNC, UPNP,DLNA etc, but I don't want the phone involved (so the kids can use it as well, they don't have phones).

I'm also aware that there are "learning remotes" that you can point your crappy remote at and it will learn it's signal and you can assign it to a button. This does exactly what I want, and I'll get one as a last ditch effort, but I'm wondering if I can do the same thing on my android box without buying another remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much reading, I ended up achieving what I wanted thanks to [CEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#CEC). Thankfully the M8, and my VIZIO TV support CEC, which I had never heard of before, and I can control the M8 with my TV remote control (actually I'm using my direct TV remote which is programmed to control the TV). The signals get passed through the HDMI cable.

I had to enable CEC on both the M8, and my TV. At first it didn't work, but I tried with another HDMI cable and it started working. Apparently not all HDMI cables implement the pins that are used to do CEC, and the cable that came with the M8 did not.

Comment: Yep, swapped cables. Stated on it in writing on the cable, HDMI with Ethernet.